# How can I match a null byte (0x00) in the Visual Studio binary editor with a find using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, find, null-character

Open a file in the Visual Studio binary editor that contains a null byte (0x00), then use the Quick Find feature (Ctrl +F) to find null bytes.

I would have thought I could use a regular expression such as \x00 to match null bytes but it doesn't work. Searching for any other hex value using this method works fine.

Is this a VS bug, 'feature', or am I just missing something? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "00" as the text and select "Match whole word" to find null bytes in the binary editor. You need to select match whole word to ensure you don't also match "00" in ascii. Just tried it so I know it works.

Comment: Thanks @MSN , works perfectly for my case... I might raise this on Connect because it sounds like a VS bug that you can't use a \x00 reg ex to find null characters in the binary editor...

Comment: Also make sure thet "use wildcards" and "use regex" option is disabled.